# CocoaPods copy resources to main bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a general framework project to be used in a family of products. I want to have a general 'Launch Screen File' stored in framework and used in all applications. The problem, xCode can only select xib file from "Copy bundle Resources" and my LaunchView.xib is a part of framework 'Resources' bundle.

Can I somehow copy specific .xib file to main bundle while running 'pod install'? Any other idea how implement Launch.xib shared between projects?

CocoaPods: 0.39.0.beta.3
xCode: 7.0

Framework .podspec

```
...
s.resource_bundles = {
    'Resources' => ['Source/Assets/Images/**/*.png',
    'Source/Assets/Xibs/**/*.xib',
    'Source/Assets/Localization/*.lproj',
    'Source/Assets/*.xcdatamodeld']
}
...
```

Project Podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Framework', :path => "../"
```